# Prettier - React Native

Tags: react-native, jsx, expo, prettier

Prettier автоматически вставляет {' '} в мой JSX код, что вызывает проблему в моём EXPO компиляторе, которая говорит что string значения могут находиться только внутри тега , что нужно добавить в options чтобы отключить вставление этих скобочек?